# Getting AWS access key from command line

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-cli

I have an AWS ECS container that runs Jenkins. It runs assuming a role and I wanted to get the access key (both id and secret access key) associated with that role using `aws cli` within bash shell. I need the key in order to sign a HTTP request being sent to another AWS service using CURL.

I have looked at both `aws iam` and `aws sts` commands and I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have figured out how to get this information. The meta-data for an instance is made available through a particular IP associated with EC2 instance. In this credentials can be found using:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/<NAME_OF_ROLE>
```